# Theory that we cannot observe everything

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, observables

If I remember physics class correctly, and if not feel free to correct me, there is a theory that shows that we can not observe everything. I think the example given was energy and space. So either we get a good image of energy or space but never both. Now my question: Which theory declares that we can not fully observe "something"?

I hope it is clear what I am asking, physics class was ages ago ^^

Comment: Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle? Uncertainties in the products of “conjugate pairs” (momentum/position) and (energy/time) were defined by Heisenberg as having a minimum value corresponding to Planck’s constant divided by 4π. 
https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Quantum_Mechanics/02._Fundamental_Concepts_of_Quantum_Mechanics/Heisenberg's_Uncertainty_Principle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you're referring to the [Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle), a part of quantum mechanics, which states that there exist pairs of so-called 'conjugate variables', like the position and momentum of a particle, which cannot be measured with infinite precision simultaneously.

(More technically, it states that the uncertainty in position, $\Delta x$, and the uncertainty in momentum, $\Delta p$, obey an inequality of the form 
$$\Delta x \, \Delta p \geq \frac12 \hbar,$$
where $\hbar=h/2\pi$ is the reduced Planck constant, so that position can be measured arbitrarily well, but only at the expense of increasing momentum uncertainty, and vice versa.)